# time coutdown in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, countdowntimer

Im trying to create a timer countdown in Corona SDK using Lua. I am quiet new to coding so I have never set one up. Any ideas how I would go about doing this.

Here is what I have so far

```
infoBar = display.newImage('infoBar.png', 280)
score = display.newText('0', 65, -2, native.systemFontBold, 14)
score:setTextColor(0)
timeLeft = display.newText('20', 175, -2, native.systemFontBold, 14)
timeLeft:setTextColor(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will do it...

```
local timeLimit = 20
timeLeft = display.newText(timeLimit, 160, 20, native.systemFontBold, 14)
timeLeft:setTextColor(255,0,0)

local function timerDown()
   timeLimit = timeLimit-1
   timeLeft.text = timeLimit
     if(timeLimit==0)then
        print("Time Out") -- or do your code for time out
     end
  end
timer.performWithDelay(1000,timerDown,timeLimit)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
local timeCounter = n
local myTimer=timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function() timeCounter = timeCounter - 1 end, n )
```

This line will reduce timeCounter variable for n times. When you finished with time, you can simply remove it

```
timer.cancel( myTimer )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Worked great.